# TV and audio hacking

Tags: surveillance, video

I have been stalked now for over a year.  I think they are doing it over the DirectTV because they can hear me and I can hear them.

Is it possible they are recording me like a movie live through video streaming?  It is impossible to figure out who it is because they are altering their voices, but it sounds like porn in the background.

Direct TV said he thought it was a private network.

Comment: cameras can be thwarted with tape, and taping an object over a microphone can mute it.

Comment: What do you mean by "they can hear me and I can hear them"? Do you talk to each other? How do you know they can hear you? What do you mean by "sounds like porn in the background"? If the voices are altered, then all background sounds would be altered, too. Can you also explain "Direct TV said he thought it was a private network." What do you mean by that?

Comment: How often do you hear them? Every day? Once a week? What kinds of things do they say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, smart devices can be hacked and used the exact way you've described : the "Smart TV" is - roughly-speaking - the same computer, with a function-dependent extra peripherials, like big screen, surround speakers built-in. You need a help from forensics to solve your case and gather an evidence for court/lawsuit.

Comment: First let's verify that the problem is in fact technical in nature.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to do testing to verify where it is coming from.  Assuming they are talking to you, unplug the power cord to the "TV-direct" box.  If this device they should be cut off mid-word/sentence.

Repeat the same test with your internet connection.

If you have wifi change the access point name,password, and verify/change to WPA2 for encryption.  Google the make model of your router, and see if it is vulnerable and replace it if it is.